# Compiles And Runs But Crashes

Tags: android, crash

So I'm trying to write code which will spawn a red circle at a random spot on the screen every 5 seconds. I wrote the code which will just spawn a red circle without repeating it every 5 seconds and it works fine. Then, when I added code (commented out) to draw another circle every 5 seconds, the program still compiled and ran but crashed immediately on my testing phone. Here is the code.

```
public class RandomCircles extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//        Timer timer = new Timer();
//       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
//            public void run() {
                setContentView(new MyView(RandomCircles.this));
//            }
//        }, 0, 5 * 1000L);//5 seconds
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_random_circles, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //800, 1162
        Random rand = new Random();
        x = rand.nextInt(getWidth());

        if(getWidth() - x < 100)
            x -= 100;
        else if(getWidth() - x > getWidth() - 100)
            x += 100;

        int y = rand.nextInt(getHeight());

        if(getHeight() - y < 100)
            y -= 100;
        else if(getHeight() - x > getHeight() - 100)
            y += 100;

        int radius;
        radius = 100;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
    }
}
```

This is the logcat:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: look in the logcat and find the stacktrace that gets printed when the app crashes. Edit your question and include the stacktrace.

Comment: first of all, consider invalidating the view instead of setting content view all over every time :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29

Comment: Why is setting the content view over and over again bad? Just want to know the reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, any action involving the user interface must be done in the main or UI thread so, brother you can not perform any action related with the User Interface on any other thread.
You can use the TimerTask in the following way,

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    setContentView(new MyView(MainActivity.this));
                }
            });
        }
      }, 0, 5 * 1000L);
```

And don't forget to read this,
[`Activity.runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: This works but instead of adding additional red circles to the screen, draws another one without keeping the other circles. How can you maintain previous circles too?

Comment: I think I read something about layers so each layer just has one shape but they can all be displayed at once?

Comment: Yes, you can display all the layers at once

Comment: How do you create these layers?

Comment: You have two ways todo that one is to create multiple views and add them in a layout and the other way is to draw multiple circles inside the view